# R : TUKEY following one-way ANOVA

Tags: r, package, anova, tukey

I conducted a one-way ANOVA in R, but I keep getting error messages when I attempt to do a Tukey post-hoc to see which treatments differ from each other.
(I would like the results to be ranked (a, ab, b, bcd...etc.)

> **DATA details:**
>
> data = "abh2"
>
> x = 6 treatments : "treatment"
>
> y= moisture readings "moist" (n=63 per treatment, total=378)

I ran a one-way ANOVA:

```
anov <- anova(lm(moist~treatment, data=abh2))
```

.# RESULTS indicate I can move to a post hoc (p<0.05):

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: moist
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
treatment   5 1706.3  341.27  25.911 < 2.2e-16 ***
```

I chose **Tukey HSD** and tried to run it with 2 methods, but get error messages for both:

*Built-in R function:*

```
TukeyHSD(anov)
# ERROR : no applicable method for 'TukeyHSD' applied to an object of class "c('anova', 'data.frame')"
```

*Agricolae package:*

```
    HSD.test(anov, "treatment", group=TRUE, console=TRUE)
    # ERROR : Error in HSD.test(anov, "treatment", group = TRUE, console = TRUE) :
argument "MSerror" is missing, with no default
```

*I found the MSerror was*

1) An "# Old version HSD.test()" (But I've just updated the agricolae package)

2) MSerror<-deviance(model)/df

So I tried:

```
HSD.test(anov, "treatment", MSerror=deviance(moist)/5, group=TRUE, console=TRUE)
 *but still* # ERROR: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Could anyone help me move ahead from here? It seems like a pretty simple problem but I've spent hours on this!

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feed back Annie-Claude, it got me on the right track that R wasn't recognizing the data as it should.

I solved the problem using this code though:

```
library(agricolae)

model<-aov(moist~treatment, data=abh2)

out <- HSD.test(model,"treatment", group=TRUE,console=TRUE)
```

It appears that the ANOVA command that I was initially using (from R base package), was simply not understood by the Tukey test I was trying to perform afterwards (with the agricolae package).

**Take-home message for me:** Try to conduct a related string of analyses in the same package!

*p.s. To obtain the p-values:*

```
summary(model)
```

*they can be converted to a dataframe like so:*

as.data.frame( summary(model)[[1]] )

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying your treatment as a factor with the following code:

`abh2$treatment <- factor(abh2$treatment)`